# Does the order of specifying B2C policies (in C#) matter?

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c

I am integrating B2C into an existing MVC web application. I have added the below section of code into the Startup.Auth.cs file, along with the code for CreateOptionsFromPolicy:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignUpSignInPolicyId));
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(EditProfilePolicyId));
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(PasswordResetPolicyId));
```

Whenever I click on the login link that specifies the policy to use is the SignUpSignIn policy, then this directs me to that policy in B2C.

```
public void SignIn()
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, Startup.SignUpSignInPolicyId);
    }
}
```

However if I open a url of the site which requires the user to be authenticated when they are not, then I am directed to the PasswordReset policy instead.

When I changed the order of the policies so that the SignUpSignIn one is the last of the three in Startup.Auth.cs, then when I click on the same link when not authenticated, then I am instead directed to the SignUpSignIn policy as I need.

My question is, does the order of specifying these policies in the StartUp.Auth.cs file matter? I have come across no documentation anywhere to suggest this is the case.

Alternatively, is there somewhere I can specify which policy to use for all/each action which require authentication when there is currently no authenticated user?

Comment: Please refer this link : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/tree/master/TaskWebApp    and this link to know in details:  https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/apps/tree/master/apps/web-dotnet-fw-owin-auth-code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has nothing to do with order, You can try putting `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(EditProfilePolicyId));` to the last and test, because it seems like when you open a url of the site which requires the user to be authenticated when they are not, you are directed to the last of three policy.
Sorry,I have not enough reputation so i can't comment.If I have any further findings, I will update my answer.